# Printer Add button not enabled in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: network-printer, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to set-up a network printer on my system.

Navigated to System Setting>>Printing and viola the Add button out there is disabled.

When i troubleshooted using Help it said that the CUPS print spooler does not appear to be running. To correct this, choose System->Administration->Services from the main menu and look for 'cups' service.

Please tell me what to do in order to add a printer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When CUPS is not running the Printers panel looks like this on my Ubunbu 12.04:

[image]

Is this what you see?

About CUPS:

- Use this command to check whether CUPS is installed:

  ```
  dpkg --list | grep ' cups '
  ```

  Typical output when installed is:

  ```
  ii  cups                1.5.3-0ubuntu4      Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - server
  ```

  If you don't see any output, install CUPS:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install cups
  ```

  and start it:

  Ubuntu 12.04: `sudo service cups start`

  Ubuntu 16.04: `sudo sudo systemctl start cups.service`
- If it is already installed it may not be running, check it like this:

  ```
  ps -ef|grep cups | grep -v grep
  ```

  Typical output when running is:

  ```
  root       925     1  0 Oct17 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/cupsd -F
  ```

  If you don't see any output CUPS is not running. Start it like this:

  Ubuntu 12.04: `sudo service cups start`

  Ubuntu 16.04: `sudo sudo systemctl start cups.service`

Could you try it and post any problems?

More information on CUPS:

- Ubuntu 12.04: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/cups.html
- Ubuntu 16.04: https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/serverguide/cups.html

Comment: it gave the following output with first one>> ii  cups-pk-helper                         0.2.1.2-1                               PolicyKit helper to configure cups with fine-grained privileges

Comment: OK, looks like you don't have CUPS installed, please install it with `sudo aptitude install cups`.

Comment: shouldn't it be sudo apt-get install cups

Comment: `aptitude` works, `sudo apt-get install cups` is also OK. There are many posts on differences between `aptitude` and `apt-get`. They are pretty equivalent for installing/removing/searching but aptitude provides some more functionality, see http://serverfault.com/questions/21105/whats-the-difference-between-apt-get-and-aptitude.

Comment: it says>> Unable to fetch some archives

Comment: Is your Ubuntu computer connected to the Internet? What do you see when you type in a terminal `host archive.ubuntu.com`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6168/discussion-between-jaume-and-vipin8169)

Comment: It turns out there was a problem with the proxy settings. vipin8169 could browse the web, but not connect to archive.ubuntu.com. After an hour I noticed we couldn't get it working and referred him to his ISP. Good luck!

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/204602/apt-get-install-not-working/204610#comment254501_204610

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/201988/printer-add-button-not-enabled/201993#comment255080_201993

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/205138/error-in-updating-the-system/205148#205148

Comment: this works with ubuntu 16.04 with ``sudo apt-get install cups``