# printers application in ububtu 14.04 not working properly

Tags: printing, ubuntu-14.04, cups

When I try to open it, it opens with a delay and shows exactly the screen shown here [Printer Add button not enabled in ubuntu 12.04](https://superuser.com/questions/489313/printer-add-button-not-enabled-in-ubuntu-12-04).

[image: picture of printing dialog]

It seems there is a problem with CUPS.
Two more bits of input:

1. Instead of "printing-localhost" my printers window opens with the title "printers-possidon.extra.cea.fr" which for some reason is stuck as the CUPS server "possidon.extra.cea.fr" this one is no longer relevant
2. I followd the instructions in [Printer Add button not enabled in ubuntu 12.04](https://superuser.com/questions/489313/printer-add-button-not-enabled-in-ubuntu-12-04) for the first point i got what seems to be the normal thing. For the second I got:

   ```
   michele@michele-ThinkPad-Edge-E530:~$ ps -ef|grep cups | grep -v grep
   root      1056     1  0 03:24 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/cups-browsed
   root      2592     1  0 03:48 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/cupsd -f
   ```

so the 1st line seems suspicious 
Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

The context is I'm trying to install a new hp deskjet printer,
and in the process I get errors related to cups, so that's another indication that the problem lies with CUPS

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured out what was the problem, so for those for whom it may be relevant:

The cups client configuration file had as server name some old network server, and it kept the printers application stuck, and also failed the hplip install.

So with

"sudo gedit /etc/cups/client.conf"

I edited the server name to

"localhost:631"

and from this point on everything worked smoothly.